# Endless input fields that write to hidden field

Tags: jquery, plugins, input

I'm looking for a jquery solution that populates a hidden field with  values from an infinite amount of input boxes. The values in the hidden field should be separated by a ';'. There should always be an empty input field. Once a value is entered into this input field, a new one should appear. When one field is emptied, the other empty field should disapear.

If a plugin is available that can do this then I'd be very happy if you could point me in the right direction.

In the meantime I've hacked something together myself which I will post as an answer.

Comment: You wrote an answer to your own question in less than 3 minutes? Looking at the answer looks like it definitely took more than 3 minutes to write it. Do you want to add it in your question or leave it as an answer?

Comment: I did this because I wanted to have it on stackoverflow for future references as I didn't find a proper solution to this yet. And in this way I wanted to contribute to the community. If there's another way, I will adapt. Why put it in the question though?

Answer (score 0):

The code below will apply this logic for every `<input type="hidden" />`field that has the `endlessinput` class applied. Might not be the most beautifull piece of code but it does what I want it to do :-)

```
$("input[type='hidden'].endlessinput").each(function (i, n) {
    $parent = $(n).parent();
    $br = $('<br />');
    // define a textbox for each value and add an additional empty one
    var createInput = function () {
        var input = $('<input id="'+guid()+'" type="text" value="" />');
        input.unbind('keyup');
        input.bind('keyup', function () {
            // rebuild the array with values
            var arr = [];
            $("input[type='text']", $parent).each(function (k, y) {
                arr.push($(y).val());
            });
            $(n).attr('value', arr.join(';'));
            // Add another input field if no empty one is available
            emptyInputs = $('input:text[value=""]', $parent).filter(function (o, p) { return $(p).val() == '' });
            if (emptyInputs.length == 0) {
                $($("br", $parent).last().length > 0 ? $("br", $parent).last()[0] : $(n)).after(createInput(), "<br />");
            } else if (emptyInputs.length > 1) {
                emptyInputs.not(':first').each(function (ix, inp) {
                    $(inp).next('br').remove()
                    $(inp).remove();
                });
            }
        });
        return input;
    }

    // get values in an array
    var values = $(n).val().split(';');
    $(values).each(function (j, x) {
        var newInput = createInput();
        newInput.attr('value', x);
        $($("br", $parent).last().length > 0 ? $("br", $parent).last()[0] : $(n)).after(newInput, "<br />");
    });
    $($("br", $parent).last().length > 0 ? $("br", $parent).last()[0] : $(n)).after(createInput(), "<br />");
});
```